# Difference between interactive bash and commands executed via ssh

Tags: ssh, ruby, rvm

I have a setup on a server of `ruby` using a tool called `rvm` (Ruby Version Manager. It works fine. rvm adds some stuff to the path so that it can control what version of Ruby I get when I just type `ruby`.

Now to manage the server I would like to send commands (using `sup` but that's not important here) to the server via ssh:

```
# this works fine
ssh myname@12.23.23.23 ls
```

but

```
# this gives an error
ssh myname@12.23.23.23 ruby
bash: ruby: command not found
```

I think it has something to do with the path but I am not sure. Instead of kludging a solution, I would like to understand to solve it right.

What is the reason for the difference or the purpose? And what's the `right` way for me to get my ruby command executed via ssh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is due to the path.

```
ssh myname@12.23.23.23 /usr/bin/ruby
```

To find the path of ruby do

```
whereis ruby
```

Comment: Makes sense. I can see that .bashrc takes pains to bail out in non-interactive sessions. Can you explain why that is generally important?